# Web page doesn't render svg

Tags: html, svg

I have a simple html page :

```css
#my_svg{
    width: 75px; 
    height: auto
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
   <div id="my_svg">
      <img src="https://svgshare.com/i/MHB.svg" alt="English flag">
   </div>
</a>
```

All I see is English flag so it seems like my svg is not loading. I'm sure about the path because I have the image as png on the same folder and it's working well. Just changing the extension.

The weird part is that I don't have any 404 error in my console. It's working when I add it throught the link https://svgshare.com/i/MHB.svg but when I use the local file it doesn't work. On my side I don't have any webserver and don't want

[image]

Comment: When [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62554136/web-page-doesnt-render-svg#) is downvoted it, it is considered bad manners to delete it and ask it again to hide the comment history and votes.

Comment: Well I don't get the point about the question, snippet changed, description changed

Comment: _“but when I use the local file it doesn't work”_ - so what does _that_ look like then? What happens when you use the context menu on the broken image, and use “open image in new tab” (or whatever the option might be called in your browser)?

Comment: @executable — Questions come with an Edit button for when you need to improve them.

Comment: @CBroe added picture

Comment: Your alt text is wrong. [This is the English Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_England). You're linking to the [Union Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_Jack).

Comment: _“added picture”_ - yeah, great. And that is supposed to answer which of the _two_ questions I asked you for clarification now? And please try and use your _words_, instead of posting images all the time.

Comment: When I open it on a new tab it's downloading the svg

Answer (score -1):

So your problem is its not working on the local file right? I think it will work if you use `<img src="./flag.svg" alt="English Flag'>`. That should work, sometimes not adding `"./"` on the `src` attribute will have issues because the browser might think it is a web link, not a path link.

Comment: you can use snippet tools and edit question code. this format answer is not approve. please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer